# How do I edit a missing template used in a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, editing, templates

I have a Microsoft Word document which was created using a template. I have only the finished document, and want to edit the template it was based on (which I don't have).  I cannot find a way to do so.

Almost all of the Google searches return ways for changing the template of an existing document but I don't want to do that. I just want to do some tweaks to the template that was used for an existing document.

How do I edit the template used in a word document?

**Note:**

- I do not have the *.dot or *.dotx file associated with the template
- I'm using MSOffice 2013

Comment: Is the goal to change just that document or to extract/recreate the template so you can apply it to other documents?  If the goal is just the current document, is there a reason you need to accomplish it by tweaking the template rather than the document, itself?  If you want to extract/recreate the template, it might clarify things for readers to include that in the question.

Comment: BTW, I believe (but not 100% sure), that when you base a document on a template, the template contents become merged with your document; you can't later select a different template and have the document change to reflect that.  I don't believe the document is treated like an overlay on the template.  If that's correct, there would be no way to extract the original template or tweak its contents.  You could only modify the document.

Answer (score 5):

#### Editing a Template

> A template is Word's guide for how your document and working
>   environment should appear. Depending on your version of Word,
>   templates can contain information on the toolbar, menus, macros,
>   styles, default text, and any number of other environmental items.
>
> Editing a template is much like editing a regular document; the only
>   difference is that the file is saved with a different filename
>   extension than regular documents. To load an existing template so that
>   you can edit it, do the following:
>
> 1. Display the Open dialog box. (In Word 2007 click the Office button and then click Open. In Word 2010 display the File tab of the
>      ribbon and then click Open. In Word 2013 display the File tab of the
>      ribbon, click Open, click Computer, and then click Browse.)
> 2. At the bottom of the dialog box, just above the Open button, is a drop-down list where you can specify the type of files you want Word
>      to list. Use the drop-down list to select either Word Templates or
>      Word Macro-Enabled Templates, depending on which type you want to
>      open.
> 3. Using the controls in the dialog box, browse through directories and disks drives as desired until the desired template files are
>      listed.
> 4. Select the desired document template.
> 5. Click the Open button.
>
> You can now make any changes desired, and then save the template again. The changes affect any future documents you base on the template.

Source [Editing a Template](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T007334_Editing_a_Template.html)

---

#### Finding Where Templates Are Stored

> It is unfortunate that Microsoft does not make it easier to modify
>   templates. The first step in modifying templates is to load one, and
>   that means you need to know where they are stored on disk.
>   Regrettably, the average user hasn't a clue where they are stored on
>   disk. The problem is that even Word Help cannot say exactly where the
>   templates folder is on any particular computer.
>
> If you want to know where your templates are stored, follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. Display the Word Options dialog box. (In Word 2007 click the Office button and then click Word Options. In Word 2010 display the
>      File tab of the ribbon and then click Options.)
> 2. Click Advanced at the left side of the dialog box.
> 3. Scroll to the bottom of the available options and click the File Locations button. Word displays the File Locations dialog box. (See
>      Figure 1.)
>
>    [image]
> 4. In the File Types list, choose User Templates. If the path for the templates is short enough, you may be able to see it in the dialog box
>      right now. If so, you can skip steps 5 and 6.
> 5. Click the Modify button (even though you won't be modifying anything.). Word displays the Modify Location dialog box.
> 6. The Look In drop-down list, at the top of the dialog box, contains the current path name used for templates.

Source [Finding Where Templates Are Stored](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T006072_Finding_Where_Templates_Are_Stored.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But as I've mentioned in the question, I want to edit the template used in a document. I do not have the template itself, but rather a doc which have used one. Can I not make changes to a template without having a *.dot or *.dotx file?

Comment: @Lizzie A template is a `.dot` or `.dotx` file. If you don't have one you can't edit it. What exactly are you trying to do? What do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

Use Save-As to save your document itself as a template (.DOTM, not .DOCX).  The "former" template has merged into your existing document.  One way to see is to hit SHIFT-F1, and see the Reveal Formatting pane -- check the box that says "Distinguish Style Source" and you will see what has been added as a style, and what was direct formatted.  Using "Draft" View will also show Style choices in the left column.

If it appears that the text has been formatted directly, then you can right-click it, choose the "Styles" drop-down, and then choose "Create A Style" from below those options.  Name the style based on how you plan to use it.

After you have extracted all the formatting information and turned it into style-based, not direct, delete any text you don't want to appear as part of the template.  This may mean ctrl-A, Delete (delete all of it), and that's ok.  You can see that your new styles are still there.

Use Save-As to save your document itself as a template (.DOTM, not .DOCX). (**Don't** make it normal.dot or normal.dotm -- give it a new name)

To test it, close out of word, re-open it, and open a new document based on that style. (You can start a blank or existing document, and then in File, Options, Add-Ins, choose Templates, and you can then attach the template you just made, and it will apply your formatting choices (if you choose to allow instant updates).

I hope this helped!